# Converting JSON response from oracle to angular 2 variable

Tags: json, angular, response, node-oracledb

I am trying to get the get the data from oracle db and displaying it. I have created a service using express api and node and able to run it successfully.
I have created angular service to fetch the data, and assign it in angular component, but i am not able to map the JSON response to the angular variable. Please check the code below and help me what i need to change in angular component.ts and how can i use that variable in html.

JSON Data from oracle DB:

```
[{"COUNT":27}]
```

angular service:

```
  getCount(): Promise<String[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json().data)
               .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

angular component.ts

```
 dataGS : String[];
getData(): void {
    this.dataService
        .getCount()
        .then(dataGS => this.dataGS = dataGS);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response does not have a property `data`, it's just an array. So instead of:

```
.then(response => response.json().data)
```

do:

```
.then(response => response.json())
```

Now you will get your array. Then as proposed by jitender you can iterate your response:

```
<div><p *ngFor="let d of dataGS ">{{d}}</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
 getCount(): Promise<String[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => {
                     response.json().map(function(item) {
                            return item['COUNT'];
                         })
                       })
               .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

in your html

```
 <div><p *ngFor="let d of dataGS ">{{d}}</p></div>
```

Comment: I am not getting any error but what should i use in html template binding on this case

Comment: Still am not getting, i doubt this line  response.json().map(function(item) {
                            return item['COUNT'];
is fetching data from response.

Comment: write console.log(response.json()) and check output

Comment: Console log output is "[object Object]"

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the help of [template bindings](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax) in angular.

For Example - 
In your component you receive `this.dataGS = [{"COUNT":27}]` after getting the data from the `db`. Then on your `html template` you can display this with the help of [Interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation----) like

```
<div>{{dataGS[0].count}}</div>
```

Comment: am getting below error while using this on html template
heroes.component.html:3 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (heroes.component.html:3)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (services.ts:477)
    at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:413)
    at callViewAction (view.ts:767)
    at execComponentViewsAction (view.ts:700)
    at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:413)
    at callViewAction (view.ts:767)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (view.ts:726)
    at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:410)

Comment: first initialize `this.dataGS = []` as an empty array in the `ngOnInit` or constructor

Comment: I am getting the below error while compiling ts file,
node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts(16,22): error TS2415: Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'.
  Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.
    Type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<T>' is not assignable to type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<R>'.
      Type 'Observable<T>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<R>'.
        Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'R'.

Comment: Could you please update on the angular version and whether you are using `HttpModule` or `HttpClient`, because `HttpClient` is something new that is introduced by angular team in version `4.3`